# Turning off automatic outlining in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Can any one tell me how to turn off automatic outlining in Visual Studio?  Outlining is the feature that collapses code into programmer defined regions.

In my opinion, there are precious few circumstances where outlining is useful.  Yes, it makes large files easier to navigate, but mostly it obscures complexity.  My preference would be to have this feature turned off by default when opening a source file.

Comment: Like two other posters, I found Options/Text Editor/C#/Advanced, but I can't find it for other document types. Good question.

Comment: Thanks for the question & answer of course. This is a good read https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `C#` > `Advanced`

Clear the checkbox `Enter outlining mode when files open`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Was driving me nuts. For others that find this by Googling: CTRL-M-O will collapse and CTRL-M-P will expand.

Comment: In VS 2010 it's under `language`/Formatting

Comment: Hmm. This appears to completely turn the feature on/off for me rather than just turning off automatic outlining.

Answer (score 4):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining.

Answer (score 2):

For VB it's Tools - Options - Text Editor - Basic - VB Specific - Enable outlining mode

Answer (score 1):

For C/C++ in Visual 2017:

Go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `C/C++` > `View`

Then under **`> Outlining`**, set `Enable Outlining` to *False*.

Comment: Although why they decided to put it in "C# > Advanced", but "C/C++ > View" is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2008, it's under Tools – Options – Text Editor – C/C++ - Formatting - Enter outlining mode when files open.