# VS2013 Outlining for Razor (.CSHTML) files

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How can I turn off outlining in Razor (.CSHTML) files in Visual Studio 2013?  I have followed the directions for doing this for C# (.CS) files ([Turning off automatic outlining in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709212/turning-off-automatic-outlining-in-visual-studio) but this does not have any effect on my Razor files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the Razor view open. 
It should be in your Edit Menu, Select 'Outlining' -> Stop Outlining

Or Ctrl +M, P

Comment: This only seems to work for the current file.  Also, when I close the file and reopen it, Visual Studio does not keep track of this preference.